# Bootstrap CSS Padding Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make an "Inbox" in bootstrap similar to Gmail's look and feel.

I am having some issues with the Panel that the mail items are in however.

http://jsfiddle.net/64t872o1/

[image]

I am having trouble getting rid of this Margin or padding and I cant figure out what it is.

I have set the margins and padding of the panel body to zero but it still remains.

```
.panel-body{
    padding: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: none;
}
```

Is there an easy way to figure out where this padding is coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing the margin that is set on the `.list-group` element.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/1ufx0916/)

```
.tab-content .list-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Here is the initial styling set in the main Bootstrap file:

```
.list-group {
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way:

```
.tab-content .list-group {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your css :

```
.tab-content .list-group{margin-bottom:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

> .list-group { margin-bottom: 0px; }